# Choose which implementation to inject at runtime spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following classes:

```
public interface MyInterface{}

public class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface{}

public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface{}

public class Runner {
        @Autowired private MyInterface myInterface;
}
```

What I want to do is decide, whilst the app is already running (i.e. **not** at startup) which Implementation should be injected into `Runner`.

So ideally something like this:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = ...
Integer request = ...

Runner runner = null;
if (request == 1) {
        //here the property 'myInterface' of 'Runner' would be injected with MyImpl1
        runner = appContext.getBean(Runner.class) 
}
else if (request == 2) {
        //here the property 'myInterface' of 'Runner' would be injected with MyImpl2
        runner = appContext.getBean(Runner.class)
}
runner.start();
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of IoC and Dependency Injection.

Comment: Are you using XML configurations or component scanning?

Comment: @ToddMurray All annotation driven, no XML at all.

Comment: inject both at startup, then at runtime switch between implementations.

Comment: You could use a factory pattern configured using spring and choose the implementation on runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare implementations with `@Component("implForRq1")` and `@Component("implForRq2")`

Then inject them both and use:

```
class Runner {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("implForRq1")
    private MyInterface runnerOfRq1;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("implForRq2")
    private MyInterface runnerOfRq2;

    void run(int rq) {
        switch (rq) {
            case 1: runnerOfRq1.run();
            case 2: runnerOfRq2.run();
            ...

        }
    }

}

...

@Autowired
Runner runner;

void run(int rq) {
    runner.run(rq);
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  Better to call a factory of some sort that returns the desired implementation than scatter switch statements all over the place.  Consider what happens when you need to add a 3rd implementation - do you modify all your code, or simply modify only the factory?

Comment: if i need 3rd impl i will simply modify this class... BTW, now, as far as i know spring (tested on >= 4.0.x) can inject all implementations of interface, just declare `@Autowired List<MyInterface>` and `run(int)` will transform to: `void run(int rq) { runners.get(rq).run(); }`... see example here: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/04/spring-injecting-lists-maps-optionals.html. To make proper order of runners implement `Ordered` in `MyInterface` implementations

Comment: If you need to this way, the `Resource (name = "implForRq2")` would be better than qualifier. THAT said, acc15's idea is solid ( I am doing something like that now), BUT the factory pattern idea is probably best - you inject the Factory, and then request a "correct" `MyInterface` instance from the Factory by supplying some criteria to the Factory instance method.

Comment: @user1588303 This is not a terrible idea. Do not forget spring is all about IoC, so that you don't bother with factories. It should be spring who creates all beans for you

Comment: Actually, yes, it is a terrible idea.  Anything short of encapsulating the details of the creation of the correct class has a bad code smell to it.  If you do not encapsulate the creating code, guess what, you are going to have creating code all over the place.